# Returning Profile Picture Bitmap. Facebook Java

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap

I have Facebook graph requests working and seem to have no problem whatsoever, However I have been trying for a while to retrieve the profile picture. But everytime I run it the bitmap seems to turn out null.

```
 public static Bitmap DownloadImageBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IMAGE", "Error getting bitmap", e);
    }
    return bm;
}
```

For Example, If I feed it this string:
        String testString = "graph.facebook.com/849993771766163/picture?type=large";

The bitmap will return null every single time..

What am I doing wrong? I suspect I am getting the url wrong but I have tried everything

Comment: Can you try it on a simpler URL (maybe a photo found on a different website)?

Comment: good point, gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
with
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis));

You may also need to create a scaled bitmap first and then set it to your final bitmap before setting it to a view.